# In iTerm2 what is the difference between the "default profile" vs. the "current profile"?

Tags: terminal

When I want to start a new tab in iTerm, it gives me a choice of the default profile vs. the current profile.  My understanding is that every time a terminal window is opened settings are read from my `/etc/bashrc` file -- so I guess that's the default.  Why might I want to open a new tab using my current profile?  Wouldn't it just be the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

iTerm2 profiles are different than bash profiles. iTerm2 profiles are set up in prefs->profiles and define things like colors and keyboard shortcuts, while your bashrc is specific to your shell.